# iOS 8.3.0 dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple, react-native

Device: 5s, 6 （シュミレーター）
iOS: 8.3.0
xCode: 8.0

作成中のアプリで操作してると以下のエラーがでて落ちます。
ちなみにReactNativeですが、RNに限らず同じようなエラー報告が色々見受けられましたが、
解決方法は見つかりませんでした。

思い当たる解決策がありましたらよろしくお願いします。

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_unsafeClaimAutoreleasedReturnValue
  Referenced from: /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/02E630D1-C8A4-4ACF-9A66-87096969AC97/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F4BCC21E-65D0-459B-BE69-79107E4CDB07/myapp.app/myapp
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_unsafeClaimAutoreleasedReturnValue
  Referenced from: /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/02E630D1-C8A4-4ACF-9A66-87096969AC97/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F4BCC21E-65D0-459B-BE69-79107E4CDB07/myapp.app/myapp
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

追加したライブラリのDeployment Targetが9.0になってたのが原因でした